# powershell xml select attribute value where clause

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a xml file with the following elements:

```
<telecom use="HP" value="tel:+1-512-555-1212" />
<telecom use="WP" value="tel:+1-512-123-4567" />
```

this returns the value of the first node:

```
$qrda.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget.patientRole.telecom[0].value
```

However I need to be able to return the node where use="HP" and I'm not certain they'll always be in the correct order.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-XPATH method:

```
($qrda.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget.patientRole.telecom | Where {$_.use -eq "HP"}).value
```

Or (thanks to Tomalak's helpful comment), using [the comparison statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object#examples) format:

```
($qrda.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget.patientRole.telecom | Where use -eq "HP").value
```

Comment: The short form, `($qrda.ClinicalDocument.recordTarget.patientRole.telecom | Where use -eq "HP")` should also be possible.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks - tested, it worked, added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath. Assuming that `$qrda` is your XML document:

```
$path = "/ClinicalDocument/recordTarget/patientRole/telecom[@use='HP']"
$telecom = $qrda.SelectSingleNode($path)
```

since that path is pretty long and overly specific we can trim it down:

```
$telecom = $qrda.SelectSingleNode("//telecom[@use='HP']")
```

Comment: This did not work for me. But seeing as how my xml doc is from the government, it's not surprising.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the government and everything with your question not showing the XML file itself. My answer is a best guess under these circumstances.